# NullPointerException outside of volley method

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-volley

When I am trying to access catagory array after this code it gives me nullpointerexception.
I am returning this array to other class. So it also produce nullpointerexception.

```
 JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(url, new JSONObject(),
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    // handle response
                    try {
                        JSONArray jarray=(JSONArray)response.get(item);
                        catagory=new String[jarray.length()][2];
                        //catagory_name=new String[jarray.length()];
                        for(int i=0;i<jarray.length();i++){
                            JSONObject jobj = (JSONObject) jarray
                                    .get(i);
                            catagory[i][1]=jobj.getString(sectionurl);
                            catagory[i][0]=jobj.getString(name);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (JSONException je){

                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // handle error
        }
    })

 String str=catagory[0][0];//AT THIS LINE AN EXCEPTION IS THROWN
```

Comment: Show stacktrace. Show line where you have this exception.

Comment: only `catagory == null || catagory[0] == null` can cause NPE here ... please learn about threading, callbacks, and basic code flow ... http://ideone.com/yVZP3Q

Comment: but my catagory reference variable(array variable) is Global

Comment: and? you are not understanding threading at all, check the code snippet from my prev comment and try to find out how it apply to your code ...

Answer (score 1):

As Selvin said, you should understand, how threads work.

In line `String str=catagory[0][0];` catagory is null.

Only after `public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {...}` it will have value, 'cause it's assync operation.